# Se puede crear una base de datos local en C# sin SQL o ninguna otra aplicación de tercera?

Tags: c#

A lo que me refiero:

existe una manera de poder almacenar datos solo usando visual studio?
 y como lo podria hacer(un ejemplo).

Comment: De que se puede, se puede... Optimo? Depende, difícil? Depende, pesado? Depende. De que depende? De lo que realmente necesitas.

Comment: Desde almacenar texto en un simple txt, xml o otro formato, de que es posible lo és. Depende de lo que necesitas.

Comment: Bueno es de almacenar datos numericos ordenados que se puedan acceder con facilidad y lo basico add, delete, update? Pero no genera algun problema en el proceso? Quisiera saber solo si hay un contra al usar estos metodos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Una manera de tener datos bien accesibles y complejos, con los que aprender (yo aprendí mucho con ello) es crearte un DataSet manualmente con tablas y trabajar con ello mediante ADO.Net. Puedes incluso guardarlos en XML de una manera fácil.

Para crear un DataSet con una Tabla que tenga tres columnas (Id, Nombre y Apellidos) podrías hacerlo así:

```
DataSet datos = new DataSet("MisDatos");
DataTable tabla = new DataTable("MiTabla");
tabla.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Id", Type.GetType("System.Int32")));
tabla.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Nombre", Type.GetType("System.String")));
tabla.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Apellidos", Type.GetType("System.String")));
datos.Tables.Add(tabla);
```

La tabla puedes vincularla a un DataGrid a través de la propiedad ItemsSource del mismo, para añadir o modificar datos.

Para añadir, modificar o borrar datos:

```
DataRow filaNueva = tabla.NewRow();
filaNueva["Id"] = 1;
filaNueva["Nombre"] = "José";
filaNueva["Apellidos"] = "García Fernández";
tabla.Rows.Add(filaNueva);
```

Por supuesto, hay otros métodos para añadir datos, crear colecciones de los datos de las tablas, etc. Pero para empezar está bien. Luego, con un poco de investigación verás las posibilidades que tiene.

Para guardar el DataSet en un archivo XML, utilizarías la siguiente instrucción:

```
datos.WriteXml("MiArchivo.xml", XmlWriteMode.WriteSchema);
```

Para recuperar el DataSet de nuevo desde el archivo:

```
datos.ReadXml("MiArchivo.xml", XmlReadMode.Auto);
```

Si investigas un poco sobre estos elementos verás como puedes crearte una estructura de datos muy similar a una base de datos de una manera fácil y sin contar con SQL Server.

Un saludo.

Comment: Si es muy practico guardar como XML y utlizar los metodos propios de los datasets, aunque actualmente en general los datasets ya casi no se usan, yo recomendaría utilizar JSON en archivos .txt, bien los puedes almacenar como otro tipo de dato no precisamente .txt, despues de que aprendas JSON que es lo que mas se usa ahorita puedes escalar al linq tmb es otra forma de almacenar datos en tipo "archivos" y es muy popular

Comment: Disculpa me confundi.. al decir linq quice decir: SQlite

Comment: SI. CristinaCarrascoAngulo. Hoy en día el JSON es el "standard". Yo le he recomendado los datasets por que es con lo que yo aprendí en su día. ;-)

Comment: Ya estoy aprendiendo ha usar ADO.net, gracias por eso , es bastante simple y facil al manipular datos. Aunque me llamo la atencion lo de JSON pero por ahora esta bien, ya que no quiero profundizar mucho y muy probablemente salte a SQL server si quiero continuar algo serio con *.net*. Pero, por ahora esta excelente gracias!

Answer (score 2):

Te paso un ejemplo de Catalogo con JSON

Anexo funcionamiento:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El archivo que se guardo contiene los siguientes datos:

```
[{"Id":1,"Nombre":"Alguien","Apellido":"Algo"},
{"Id":2,"Nombre":"Persona","Apellido":"Apellido"},
{"Id":3,"Nombre":"Otro","Apellido":"OtroAp"}]
```

La liga del fuente por si lo quieres revisar:
[Codigo Fuente en C#](https://drive.google.com/open?id=15l_QsOFnAQXXK5-q3WJ8e01jJTcnJl8B)

Explicación:

La estructura del proyecto quedo así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cree un archivo DataAccess para el acceso a datos, lo que hace es recibir el nombre del archivo que usara, y lee y escribe en el:

```
class DataAccess
    {
        private string DataFile;

        public DataAccess(string file)
        {
            this.DataFile = file;
            if (!File.Exists(this.DataFile))
            {
                //Si no existe crea el archivo
                FileStream fs = File.Create(this.DataFile);
                fs.Close();
            }

        }

        public void Save(string values)
        {
            //Borro el archivo anterior
            if (File.Exists(this.DataFile))
            {
                File.Delete(this.DataFile);
            }
            //Creo el archivo nuevo con la informacion actualizadad
            using (FileStream fs = File.Create(this.DataFile))
            {
                Byte[] info = new UTF8Encoding(true).GetBytes(values);
                // Add some information to the file.
                fs.Write(info, 0, info.Length);
            }
        }

        public string Read()
        {
            // Open the stream and read it back.
            string s = "";
            using (StreamReader sr = File.OpenText(this.DataFile))
            {
                s = sr.ReadLine();
            }
            return s;
        }
    }
```

Cree un archivo Pesona que es el Modelo de datos o mas bien tiene los atributos que una persona debe tener:

```
public partial class Persona
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Nombre { get; set; }
    public string Apellido { get; set; }
}
```

Cree un archivo PersonaDL (DL = Data Layer o Capa de Datos), que administra el archivo que representa la base de datos para PERSONAS:

```
partial class PersonaDL
{
    private string File { get; set; }
    //Clase que administra los archivos guardados
    private DataAccess DataAccess;
    private List<Persona> PersonasList;
    private string PersonasData;

    public PersonaDL(string file)
    {
        this.File = file;
        this.DataAccess = new DataAccess(this.File);
    }

    private void Read()
    {
        //Leeo el archivo
        this.PersonasData = this.DataAccess.Read();
        //Convierto el archivo a una lista de personas, si es que tiene datos
        this.PersonasList = this.PersonasData?.Length > 0 ? JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Persona>>(this.PersonasData) : new List<Persona>(); 
    }

    private void Save()
    {
        //Convierto los datos a string 
        this.PersonasData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(this.PersonasList);
        //guardo los datos en el archivo
        this.DataAccess.Save(this.PersonasData);
    }

    public int Save(Persona persona)
    {
        Read();
        int id = 1;

        if (Exist(persona.Id))
        {
            //Si existe solo actualizo
            var p = this.PersonasList.First(x => x.Id == persona.Id);
            p.Nombre = persona.Nombre;
            p.Apellido = persona.Apellido;
        }
        else
        {
            //Obtengo el id nuevo
            if (PersonasList.Count > 0)
            {
                id = this.PersonasList.Max(x => x.Id)+1;
            }
            persona.Id = id;
            //Si no existte inserta uno nuevo
            this.PersonasList.Add(persona);
        }

        //Agergo la persona nueva a la lista de personas
        Save();
        return id;
    }

    public void Delete(int id)
    {
        Read();
        //Busco la persona con el 
        Persona persona = new Persona();
        if (PersonasList.Count > 0)
        {
            persona = this.PersonasList.First(x => x.Id == id);
        }
        //Si la encontro la borro
        if (persona.Id > 0)
        {
            this.PersonasList.Remove(persona);
        }
        Save();
    }

    private bool Exist(int id)
    {
        Persona persona = new Persona();
        if (PersonasList.Count > 0)
        {
            persona = this.PersonasList.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == id);
        }
        return persona?.Id > 0;
    }

    public List<Persona> Get()
    {
        Read();
        return this.PersonasList;
    }

    public Persona Get(int id)
    {
        Read();
        Persona persona = new Persona(); 
        if (PersonasList.Count > 0)
        {
            persona = this.PersonasList.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == id);
        }
        return persona;
    }
}
```

Y por ultimo cree un formulario que muestra y administra la informacion con algunas funciones básicas como: Guardar, eliminar, actualizar.

```
public partial class Catalogo : Form
{
    private PersonaDL PersonaDL;
    private Persona Persona;

    public Catalogo()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        PersonaDL = new PersonaDL("Persona.dat");
        Clear();
    }

    private void btnNuevo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Clear();
    }

    private void Clear()
    {
        this.txtId.Text = "";
        this.txtNombre.Text = "";
        this.txtApellido.Text = "";
        this.txtId.Focus();
    }

    private void Find()
    {
        //Si presiono Enter que lance la consulta de los datos
        if (txtId.Text.Trim().Length > 0)
        {
            int id = 0;
            id = Int32.Parse(txtId.Text == "" ? "0" : txtId.Text);
            if (id > 0)
            {
                Persona = PersonaDL.Get(id);
                if (Persona?.Id > 0)
                {
                    ShowData();
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Persona no encontrada.");
                    Clear();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void txtId_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
        {
            Find();
        }
    }

    private void ShowData()
    {
        //this.txtId = Persona.Id;
        this.txtNombre.Text = Persona.Nombre;
        this.txtApellido.Text = Persona.Apellido;
    }

    private void btnEliminar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.txtId.Text.Trim().Length > 0)
        {
            int id = 0;
            id = Int32.Parse(txtId.Text == "" ? "0" : txtId.Text);
            if (id > 0)
            {
                PersonaDL.Delete(id);
                MessageBox.Show("Persona Eliminada");
                Clear();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Consulte una persona antes.");
        }
    }

    private void txtId_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Find();
    }

    private void btnGuardar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Persona = new Persona();
        int id = 0;
        id = Int32.Parse(txtId.Text == "" ? "0" : txtId.Text);
        Persona.Id = id;
        Persona.Nombre = this.txtNombre.Text.Trim();
        Persona.Apellido = this.txtApellido.Text.Trim();

        var idResult = PersonaDL.Save(Persona);

        MessageBox.Show("Persona Guardada id: " + idResult.ToString());
        Clear();
    }
}
```

Esto mismo mas o menos así se podría replicar a cualquier modelo de datos, y básicamente abarca varios temas muy necesarios hoy en día como LinQ, Modelo de datos en base a Clases de Entidad, salvo porque es Windows Form, que igual se podría adaptar a un Web y así aprendes Web también.  Espero que te sea de ayuda este ejemplo.